# Incomplete search results for known keyword

Tags: bug, search

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25618382/372643) earlier, I looked for previous answers mentioning one of the methods to use, which I know to be `setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm`. I remember writing a few answers about this, so I know they are there.

Yet, [a direct search for "setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm" in the top right box](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm) only yields two results:

- [How can you test that an SSL client library is properly verifying the certificate of the server to which it connects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279683/how-can-you-test-that-an-ssl-client-library-is-properly-verifying-the-certificat/17282319#17282319)
- [Secret Key SSL Socket connections in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737970/secret-key-ssl-in-java/22738568#22738568)

A Google search for "site:stackoverflow.com setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm" shows there are indeed more results, for example:

- [Netty SSL hostname verification support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315623/netty-ssl-hostname-verification-support/13316257#13316257)
- [How should I do hostname validation when using JSSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139448/how-should-i-do-hostname-validation-when-using-jsse/18174689#18174689)
- [Setting SSLContext to jdbc connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021465/setting-sslcontext-to-jdbc-connection/15021924#15021924)

Shouldn't these be found using the Stack Overflow search box?

Comment: Hang on... you actually use the search box in the top corner?! Kudos to you!

Comment: @Tanner so do I and I [love it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: @mehow **most** of the time I just find it easier using google as opposed to learning all of the intricacies of that search box. It's crying out for an advanced search control that simplifies the kind of searches that are detailed on that page.

Comment: @Tanner yes it would be nice but since this is a site aimed at programmers I quite enjoy the way it's designed to challenge us ;)

Comment: @mehow look what you made me do: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/can-we-have-a-simple-advanced-search

Answer (score 22):

Text in codeblocks is not split like regular text when indexed; the surrounding syntax is not stripped when indexing. Specifically, the preceding identifier and dot are included in the indexed term. Because of that, your sample posts do not contain *just* `setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm`; they contain the term `sslParams.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm` instead.

Your two hits contain the keyword *outside of code blocks* and are split according to text rules (so split on different word boundaries), so these are found.

Search with a wildcard instead:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=*setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm
```

That search [finds 10 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=*setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm).

Those 8 extra results all have a full stop before the identifier; searching for `*.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm` instead gives you just those 8 results for example.

Code is treated differently from text because there syntax like dots matter; my guess is that the elastic search indexer uses some general rules of thumb that should work across the broadest possible spectrum of languages. Dots are not seen as word delimiters, but parentheses are.

Strangely enough, code *is* stemmed; you can search for `SSLParameter` (singular) and find posts where only `SSLParameters` (plural) is used *in a code block*.

Comment: Sure, but in most languages, dots and brackets are reasonable separators for keywords one way or another. Don't you think it would make sense to be able to search this way too?

Comment: @Bruno: It would make total sense; I merely tried to document the behaviour here and how you can work around it. :-)