# Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange - Advanced Search

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

I thought it would be nice to have an advanced search that exposed some of the search functionality that's hidden away on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

I think it would make it simpler for users, especially those that aren't aware of it, to search for questions they are interested in if there was a user interface to do it from.

Here's a peek of what I mocked up:

<kbd>[image: Advanced Search]</kbd>

I've created a working example that exposes **some of the functionality** available in the search box by building up a search URL. The initial criteria on the demo, shows:

- Questions created this month
- With a positive score
- In your tags
- With 0 answers

### [Stack Overflow Advanced Search - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qzfa9ft/8/embedded/result/)

The fiddled version searches Stack Overflow and launches results in a new tab.

### Stack Snippet Version - Meta.SE only (Sandboxed)

The snippet version pushes the results in to an iframe as it prevents launching new windows / redirecting from the sand-boxed environment, so it only searches this meta site. I can't bypass this as far as I'm aware.

```js
$('.btnUpdate').click(

  function() {
    var site = document.getElementById('site').value;
    var link = 'http://' + site + '/search?q=';

    if (document.getElementById('tags').value.length > 0) {
      link += document.getElementById('tags').value;
    }

    link = appendLink(link, 'answers', 'answers:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'score', 'score:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'views', 'views:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'created', 'created:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'lastactive', 'lastactive:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'title', 'title:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'body', 'body:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'user', 'user:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'infavorites', 'infavorites:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'intags', 'intags:');
    link = appendLinkWithBool(link, 'hasaccepted', 'hasaccepted:');
    link = appendLinkWithBool(link, 'hascode', 'hascode:');
    link = appendLinkWithBool(link, 'closed', 'closed:');
    link = appendLinkWithBool(link, 'duplicate', 'duplicate:');
    link = appendLinkWithBool(link, 'locked', 'locked:');

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    //window.open(link, '_blank');

    var frame = document.getElementById('myFrame');
    frame.src = link;
  });

function appendLink(link, ctrl, param) {
  if (document.getElementById(ctrl).value.length > 0) {
    return link + '+' + param +
      document.getElementById(ctrl).value;
  }
  return link;
}

function appendLinkWithBool(link, ctrl, param) {
  if (document.getElementById(ctrl).value !== 'exclude') {
    return link + '+' + param +
      document.getElementById(ctrl).value;
  }
  return link;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 10pt;
  height: 100%;
}
span,
input {
  display: block;
}
.split {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.split-r {
  width: 52%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="split">
  <div>
    <span>Search Site: (without http://) <sub>(limited to meta with sand-box)</sub></span>
    <input id='site' type='text' value='meta.stackoverflow.com' disabled />
  </div>
  <div class="split">
    <h4>Tags</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>Single: [tag-1]</li>
      <li>Multiple AND: [tag-1] and [tag-2]</li>
      <li>Multiple OR: [tag-1] or [tag-2]</li>
    </ul>
    <h4>User Operators</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>User: mine, me, or a user id</li>
      <li>In Favorites: mine or a user id</li>
      <li>In Tags: mine</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="split">
    <h4>Numeric</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>Single value: 50</li>
      <li>Range: 50..75</li>
    </ul>
    <h4>Dates</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>Year: 2014</li>
      <li>Year and Month: 2014-12</li>
      <li>Full: 2014-12-31</li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="split">
    <span>Tags: </span>
    <input id='tags' type='text' value='' />
    <span>Title: </span>
    <input id='title' type='text' />
    <span>Body: </span>
    <input id='body' type='text' />
    <span>Answers: </span>
    <input id='answers' type='text' value='0' />
    <span>Score: </span>
    <input id='score' type='text' value='1' />
    <span>Views: </span>
    <input id='views' type='text' value='' />
    <span>Created:</span>
    <input id='created' type='text' value='2014-09' />
    <span>Last Active:</span>
    <input id='lastactive' type='text' value='' />
  </div>
  <div class="split">
    <span>User: </span>
    <input id='user' type='text' value='' />
    <span>In Favourites: </span>
    <input id='infavorites' type='text' value='' />
    <span>In Tags: </span>
    <input id='intags' type='text' value='mine' />
    <span>Has Accepted Answer:</span>
    <select id='hasaccepted'>
      <option value='exclude'></option>
      <option value='true'>true</option>
      <option value='false'>false</option>
    </select>
    <span>Has Code:</span>
    <select id='hascode'>
      <option value='exclude'></option>
      <option value='true'>true</option>
      <option value='false'>false</option>
    </select>
    <span>Closed:</span>
    <select id='closed'>
      <option value='exclude'></option>
      <option value='true'>true</option>
      <option value='false'>false</option>
    </select>
    <span>Duplicate:</span>
    <select id='duplicate'>
      <option value='exclude'></option>
      <option value='true'>true</option>
      <option value='false'>false</option>
    </select>
    <span>Locked:</span>
    <select id='locked'>
      <option value='exclude'></option>
      <option value='true'>true</option>
      <option value='false'>false</option>
    </select>
    <input type='button' value='Show me the Posts' class='btnUpdate' />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="split-r" style="height: 100%;">
  <iframe id="myFrame" src="http://meta.stackoverflow.com" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

### Stack Exchange Version:

I figured this functionality would work across the Stack Exchange network, so I've created a version of this demo that allows users to enter a URL. I was debating whether to post on **meta.stackexchange**, but figured I'd just update the demo on here first and see if migration was suggested:

### [Stack Exchange Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qzfa9ft/6/embedded/result/)

The only addition was the inclusion of a "Search Site" input control, the rest is unchanged:

<kbd>[image: New search]</kbd>

Feel free to modify and improve the samples if you so please.

<sup>PS: It's only been tested very lightly!</sup>

### October 2016 Bump / Update

So the advanced search is still pretty much hidden functionality apart from those users in the know.

For example, it's not straight forward to get the advanced search tips as there's not direct link to the [Search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search). You can do a search and you get the advanced search tips, which are collapsed under a link. Here's another mockup with how it could look:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: -1 for not making it work in a [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) here rather than jsfiddle.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i tried but it prevented launching a new window :-(

Comment: Your UI doesn't cover the option to use ranges; `score:50..75` for example.

Comment: Wait... did you just ask for a search that is *simple* and *advanced*? ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber yeah, just like me!

Comment: This is how we keep out the non-programmers.

Comment: @Servy Make it a privilege to access along with the loss of ads on questions: 200 rep to use. :) (This suggestion was made in jest, before I get flamed for it. I would enjoy advanced search, but don't find the current search methods that bad myself)

Comment: @Tanner: of course, I could go on with pointing out what is missing; what about all the boolean operators (accepted (answer and question variants), lock status, wiki status, etc), the user operators (`user:...`, `infavorites`, `intags:mine`), the title and body operators, etc.? That's the thing with the advanced search, there is a lot there to cover.

Comment: The "Advanced Search Tips" expandable on the search results page and the link to the help page it contains could be more prominent, but I think programmers would prefer to handle the search syntax on their own rather than using a lot of text fields -- if you could even make a reasonable UI that covered all or most of the options.

Comment: related: [Better support for search by both intersection and union of multiple tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231693/137096)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've added functionality for boolean operators, user operators, as well as title and body searching, which makes it a slightly more useful demo

Comment: There's already the [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), but you need to know SQL.

Comment: @wumm Thanks, I'm aware of that. This would be a simpler version of what you can do there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters stack snippet added, but limited to meta because of the sandboxed environment.

Comment: Any advanced search functionality should search the entire Stack Exchange network _by default_, not simply Stack Overflow.

Comment: @chb I'm not sure what your point is? this is a demo based on SO, if it was implemented it would be built in to the main engine, thus it would work across any site in the network.

Comment: @Tanner It's not apparent to me, from the screenshots and description above, that the _default_ behavior is to search the entire Stack Exchange community, and that the user must take an additional step to deliberately configure the search to limit it to Stack Overflow. I think there are a good many questions asked and answered in other sites that are often overlooked by users of Stack Overflow simply because they do not bother to do an Exchange-wide search. Having the _default behavior_ be a search of the entire network might go some way toward remedying this situation.

Comment: @chb feel free to add an answer making that suggestion

Comment: You might be interested in my [Advanced Search Helper userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011)

Comment: @SamuelLiew thanks, I'll take a look