# Multi tag search of questions

Tags: support, search, tag-search

When searching questions I can select a tag say [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) but how can I search for multiple tags at once and only return the questions that have all the tags.

Comment: Use 2 tags together in the search box: [sql][sql-server] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+sql-server, to return either tag: [sql] or [sql-server]. Also you can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and for an advanced search, perhaps read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/can-we-expose-the-advanced-search-capabilities)

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise i missed out specifics. I referring to when I use SO on my phone. As soon as I touch one tag it returns the results. I need it to hold off until I've selected all required tags.

Comment: The same applies. If you click on "questions" on the menu, then where it says "all questions" with the magnifying glass, you can enter your search terms as specified.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to just tap the tags in the menu. Oh well thanks for replies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo+bar`

In the search box, this is `[foo] [bar]`, and searching for `[foo] [bar]` *takes you* to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo+bar`.

Note that "and" is the default combiner. You can explicitly state "and" if you prefer to be explicit: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo+and+bar`. From this, it should be obvious that to do the *or* search, you can use: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo+or+bar`

Comment: He's after `AND` logic as opposed to `OR`

Comment: @Tanner my bad; replace "or" with "and" then ;p

Answer (score 2):

You can also type on the search bar like this:

[tag] and [anotherTag]

or

[tag] or [anotherTag]