# How do I search for 2 tags at the same time?

Tags: support, tags, search

I search `[c] [function]` no results. I search `c function` Java results. Simply, how do I do what I am describing? How do I search for 2 tags at the same time?

Comment: Works fine for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi tag search of questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270907/multi-tag-search-of-questions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get a list of questions tagged with *both* [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function), then you should use the following search query:

```
[c] [function] is:question
```

which will return the following page worth of results:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+%5Bfunction%5D+is%3Aquestion

Note that there is an implicit Boolean AND operator between the two tags.

If you omit the `is:question` option, then you will get far more results, since answers will also be included.

You can get the same results using the "Filter" widget, which allows you to enter the tags graphically (and obviates the need for the explicit `is:question` option):

[image]

The result is this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+function

---

If you want to search for questions tagged with *either* [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) *or* [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function), then you should use the following search query:

```
[c] or [function] is:question
```

which will return the following page worth of results:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bfunction%5D+is%3Aquestion

Note the use of the Boolean OR operator between the two tags.

You can use the same Boolean OR operator in the "Filter" widget:

[image]

The result is this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20or%20function

Comment: As a small addendum, a query of the form `[c] or [javascript] [function]` will return functions tagged as `c` *or* `javascript` and in either case contain `function`. So it's resolved as if the expression was "(`c` or `javascript`) and `function`". However, I don't think you can do something like  "(`c`  and `function`) or `javascript`" for either `c` + `function` tags on a question *or* only the `javascript` tag on a question. I believe there was a feature to add grouping syntax that but I don't think it was done (also I can't find it).