# I'm getting really, really tired of filtering through the garbage... any tips?

Tags: discussion, answers, fastest-gun

I've been trying to answer questions as best as I can. I admit, I want the rep, but I always try to make my answers as high-quality as possible. I'm here to try and help people who deserve help, not gain imaginary internet points.

That said, I've mostly found questions to answer through one strategy: [sitting on a list of tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+java+or+javascript+or+actionscript-3+or+c). This *works*, but it is more of a chore than anything. There are a number of problems with my current method:

- 95% of all questions are utter, utter garbage. Even if a question looks interesting enough to click on, most of the time I simply downvote, close vote, and move on. Finding the good questions in the deluge of crap is like (to use the cliché) finding a needle in a haystack.
- Of the small set of questions which are actually good, the [fastest gun in the west problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/188673) makes contributing answers that are actually *high-quality* severely less effective in gaining imaginary internet points. Sure, okay, this is not my main priority, but it's still discouraging to spend fifteen minutes researching and typing out a high-quality answer only to have it be severely outvoted by a much less comprehensive answer that was posted within two minutes of the question being asked.

  - This is actually exacerbated by the fact that there are so many terrible questions. The good questions get drowned out by the crap, so people tend not to see questions that are more than a few minutes old. Therefore, most of the votes on an answer accumulate while the question is still fresh, since voters don't see the question many minutes later.
- Most of the good questions actually *require* a large time investment. Especially in the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tags, many of the questions are about libraries I am not intimately familiar with. Answering those questions takes time for me to ensure my answer is correct. Due to the above issues, answering these questions is rarely worth my time. I can gain many times the rep simply by camping for the questions I can answer in 30 seconds and getting bizarre amounts of upvotes for a one-liner any person proficient in the language could've spit out in under a minute.

I don't answer *that many* questions, and I only have 170 answers at the time of this writing, but currently my second-highest voted answer is a [painfully obvious Java one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14847842/465378), while [my elaborate answer with multiple solutions and two JSFiddle examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23774287/465378) has less than half the votes.

I'm not trying to turn this into a generic "woe is me, I deserve more rep" post, but I'm trying to make one thing clear: I am starting to get really frustrated with participating on Stack Overflow. I know the "recommended" homepage is supposed to help with this, but it hasn't thus far, and I can't imagine it will ever get all that effective. I'd love to be proven wrong, but I suppose I'm cynical.

So. That was more of a rant than anything else, but my question still stands: what are the current best strategies to finding good questions to answer that best mitigate the problems described above? Is the system just broken beyond all repair? I hope not, because SO has managed to almost singlehandedly change the way programming problems are handled on the internet, but I'm worried that I'm not alone in getting fed up with this onslaught of worthless, low-quality posts. If we don't figure out a better way to get good questions in the hands of good answerers (and adequately reward both parties), this site will continue to decay.

Comment: In your [list of tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+java+or+javascript+or+actionscript-3+or+c) there are 91 questions with open bounty. There you may not have to worry about  the fastest gun in the west problem.

Comment: @AzizShaikh That's a good point, actually, I tend to forget about the bounty system's existence. I'll take a look at that!

Comment: Have you tried using an auto-refresher? Most bad questions are obvious from their title. So if you use an auto-refresher you can scan through hundreds of questions without having to move a finger.

Comment: @Mysticial I usually just use the "X questions with new activity" WebSockets updater. Do you have something you recommend that's superior to that?

Comment: So the sockets update requires you to actually click. If there's only 1 good question per 1000, that's too much effort. So I set my favorite tags and put an auto-refresher on the homepage (or the recommended tab) and let it play by itself. That way, I can just sit and watch, or go about my day and occasionally glance over to scan for anything that might be good. The downside is that you probably won't win any FGITW since you'll be ~30 seconds behind everyone who is using the websockets.

Comment: @Mysticial Hmm, that sounds reasonable, I might give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexisKing The other downside is that you learn to subconsciously ignore anything that is bad or not interesting. So you spend a lot less time cleaning up the site. (so the crap remains for everyone else) But hey, that's still better than getting frustrated and ragequitting. :)

Comment: [My highest-voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6120990) is crap as far as I'm concerned, but apparently people find it useful. The ones that I'm most proud of, [e.g.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16113046), just don't have a wide enough appeal. That just the way it is. You might find the SO blog post [The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) to be a good read. But don't stop trying for quality. It's appreciated, even if it doesn't get you points.

Comment: I had the same problem. I found myself ending up shooting from the hip with some answers out of pure frustration and ultimately decided to just give up. I was sitting on the angular tag and watched the quality of questions plunge to the point where it just became hopeless to find anything even remotely interesting to answer. My highest voted answer is a copypaste from the docs, and it's depressing. Now I just do review-tasks instead. It doesn't give rep but at least it helps cleaning up some of the mess.

Comment: @jscs Your points are sound, I just don't like them much, I'm afraid.

Comment: As a side note, I deliberately try to spend time on the new questions in my favored tags. After all, when I've got a 90-second compile to wait for, that's enough time to read, comment on, and close almost any bad question, but not enough time to answer almost any good one.

Comment: see **[Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)**

Comment: @gnat Mmm, yes, that seems to be more or less an exact duplicate.

Comment: FWIW SE team seems to acknowledge the issue and even [attempt to address it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235163/165773) but, as indicated by your own question, they don't have much luck in this so far. If you're interested to watch their efforts, consider following tag [meta-tag:se-quality-project] here at MSO and at MSE

Comment: One possible option would be to up-skill yourself in a tag which has lesser followers. That way you will both improve your own knowledge base and also get more time to write a quality answer (which could help people for years to come) without having to worry about FGITW. I don't think I post great answers, but I found that option quite helpful.

Comment: You finally understood how SO works! give yourself a pat on the back

Comment: Have you considered taking a (short) break from the site? I think crap fatigue may be the more important issue here...

Comment: _I'm not trying to turn this into a generic "woe is me, I deserve more rep" post..._ Well, maybe it's not generic.

Comment: If you were really willing to help out people in the first place, you would post your so-called elaborated answers just for the sake of helping. If a crappy short answer gets all the up votes, why would you care?

Comment: @MelanciaUK: Because when a crappy short answer gets all the upvotes it diminishes the effectiveness of other answers. After all, the point of voting is to sort the good answers over the not-so-good ones. Granted, some late in-depth answers do eventually rise to the top (bar the early, accepted answer), but it doesn't always happen, which is unfortunate.

Comment: It would be nice if you could filter out questions based on keywords in the body. I'd start with the word "Scanner".

Comment: @MelanciaUK Quite often though by the time you post your elaborate and thoroughly researched answer, OP has already accepted one of the crappy answers and is unlikely that anyone will stay behind to read yours.

Comment: on "fastest gun in the west problem": I see that [you provide most of your answers within 15 minutes of a question being created](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/226245/fast-gun-distribution-for-a-user).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, yes I do. I'm not pretending I'm not part of the problem. I've gamed the system as much as anyone else, partially because it seems to be somewhat necessary.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian nice query...

Comment: read a [poem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966157/how-to-display-random-strings-or-array-in-a-javascript-generated-poem). On second thought....

Comment: StackOverflow rep points are real, not imaginary. Discuss amongst yourselves.

Comment: I started trying to answer questions because I want the ability to downvote questions which show obvious lack of patience, research, or even rudimentary understanding of the problem. I also wanted to downvote quick one-line answers that were nonsense. But I found the process of answering SO questions so distasteful that I didn't even bother getting to 125 rep. I will say this; those of you writing out long, useful answers, I read them. If it's something where I ended up on that question because of my own hunt for answers, I read them, I use them to learn, and I upvote them.

Comment: @Alexis, did you try [my plugin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271684/im-getting-really-really-tired-of-filtering-through-the-garbage-any-tips/271821#271821)? I've been finding some gems filtering the questions with it ;)

Answer (score 55):

There is a viable—and, I think, non-malicious—strategy for getting rep points while still writing good answers, which I stumbled onto by accident.

I tend to write iteratively—start off with just the key points, then add in examples and explanations until it's way too long, then try to trim things back. And I like to commit often.*

So, as a consequence, I often write one of the first decent-but-not-great answers, getting the FGTW rep, but then my final version is (I hope) pretty solid, also getting me good-answer rep. It took me a few months to notice the effect, but after I started to pay attention, and did a few experiments (just waiting on my first commit), I'm pretty sure it's real.**

As an even more important consequence, the early commits mean I often discover that someone else has written a really good answer before I've put in too much work, so I can just delete my answer (unless I think I have something important to add) and not waste any more time.

I don't think this hurts anything. In fact, I think it helps. As long as I finish up the good answer I intended, that's the most important thing. If my eventually-good answer takes potential votes away from a half-assed answer that's never going to be expanded beyond a one-liner, that's not a bad thing either. And the fact that I sometimes get to abandon answering early and creating two competing answers that don't add anything to each other… well, maybe that's just neutral, but it's not bad.

However, as ivami points out, these edits do bump the question on the activity list. While that has the minor benefit of driving people toward a (hopefully) good question, it also has the negative effect of driving them to a good question that already has a (hopefully) good answer, when they were trying to find a question in need of an answer…

---

<sub>* In case it isn't obvious why: I hate when I accidentally delete something important, or go into a tunnel or run out of time when I'm halfway through revising something.</sub>

<sub>** I suppose if I did a more scientific study and discovered that I was getting a lot more FGTW rep than good-answer rep I'd be a bit disappointed… but the beauty is that I don't actually know, so I don't have to be disappointed. :)</sub>

Comment: I definitely do this, and I think it's certainly helpful. It's a pain that it's necessary, but such is the system.

Comment: Well, you keep bumping the question with your edits, making it even harder for others to find stuff to answer.

Comment: @AlexisKing: I don't find it a pain… but that's probably because, except in cases that are complicated enough that I need emacs to do the editing, I find it the most natural way to work anyway. Except for the lack of a "save and keep open" button.

Comment: @ivarni: Well, edits get coalesced by the system (for example, this answer shows 1 edit, not 12)… but you're right, that's a possible consequence I hadn't intended. That being said, I generally don't put that kind of effort into something that isn't a good question, so (assuming I'm not a terrible judge of good questions…) it's not as bad as it sounds at first.

Comment: This is a good summary of how I tend to post as well. Post the short-short tldr version with the solution, add in context and samples and links and further insights after that.

Comment: This is a good tactic because it allows you to quit early if you see better answers popping up from other authors. So you can keep improving your answer as long as it makes sense to do so — and then leave without regrets.

Comment: I've done this before and got shouted at by a high-rep user. I might post a quick snippet, submit, then go back and add some more explanation. I'm not sure that it's actually a good strategy (and I try not to do it so much anymore). The most extreme (and not something I've ever done, but saw just recently) is to post something along the lines of "sounds like a case for linq, I'll post a solution in a moment", which I flagged as not an answer because that's BS.

Comment: Also, I think if you post a quick (and not entirely complete) answer you may actually discourage other users from posting. I'm much more likely to click on a question if it shows as having `0` answers rather than one with `1` answer on the assumption that the question with an answer is more likely to *have an answer* already.

Comment: @MattBurland: Yes, it's definitely important to make sure the initial version of the answer is at least decent enough to stand on its own. If you post "I'll put a solution in a moment", besides the fact that you're actively gaming the system for rep, you're risking the possibility that your WiFi will go down or you'll get called away to an emergency or a bus will vault 30 feet in the air and through your window, and then you've written a bad answer.

Comment: It's like my moms always said: always wear clean underwear and make sure your answer is at least decent enough to stand on its own in case you get hit by a bus.

Comment: Just make sure your first "revision" is a good answer by itself. I often see people post something that is garbage just so they are first, then they come back and edit it wondering why it was downvoted because *now* it's a good answer. But personally if I see a crap answer I'm going to downvote it and I'm not going to come back to see if it was improved.

Comment: @eddie_cat: Has that not already been covered in the answer, and Martijn's comment, and my last comment? I think "decent" covers it pretty well, but I can explain it in more detail. (I can always write _more_; the hard part is the opposite…) For example: It has to be good enough that I wouldn't downvote it, and wouldn't expect any other reasonable user to do so—but, more important, it has to actually answer the asker's question (and ideally help similar questions). Does that need to go into the text?

Comment: @abarnert not sure why you're calling me out but not the other comments, lol. I wasn't trying to say your answer was bad, and I didn't downvote it. What's your problem?

Comment: @eddie_cat: I wasn't "calling you out", I was taking your comment seriously and responding to it. If you think the answer doesn't already cover that well enough, I should probably edit the answer so that it does, right?

Answer (score 27):

### Pick Less Popular Tags

The problem with the more popular tags is they are saturated with both lots of questions and followers, therefore the ratio of questions that you can answer is far lower than if you select a few less popular tags.

I've found it more rewarding picking a tag that sometimes only gets a few questions per hour, but the quality is usually higher and there are less people actively answering so you don't have to worry about Quick Draw McGraw:

[image]

### Use the Advanced Search

If you have a read of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), there are numerous queries you can use to try to find higher quality questions that need an answer. For example, you might want to look for:

**[Questions asked today, in your tags, that aren't closed, with no answers and a positive score](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20answers:0%20score:1%20created:2014-09-19%20intags:mine%20closed:false)**

I recently asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/can-we-expose-the-advanced-search-capabilities) to try to expose the advanced search functionality.

I also created a demo of the advanced search, which I have been using to find questions to answer:

**[Advanced Search Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qzfa9ft/5/embedded/result/)**

Comment: Though if you want to pitch in to maintain the site, you should not filter out the negative score questions, because you will probably want to cast a close vote on those.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett You're misinterpreting my answer. I'm not suggesting that is the only thing you should do. It's just an example of how to find an answerable question that is likely to be higher quality. Personally, it depends what mood I'm in. If I want to answer a question and there's nothing jumping out at me, I'll look at specialist tags or use the advanced search. If I want to do reviewing, I'll hit the queues. If I want to cast votes I'll generally go through my tags and work down the list.

Comment: Where is the code snippet for the *Advanced Search Demo*?!?

Comment: @MaximeLorant Stack snippets don't allow launching new tabs / redirects out of the sand-boxed environment as mentioned in the OP. I did try :)

Comment: Oh yeah, indeed :-) Damn, we got an almost perfect tool...

Comment: That search query is pretty powerful, totally bookmarking that.

Comment: [Quick Draw McGraw reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533).

Answer (score 23):

I struggle with the same thing, because I really enjoy putting in some effort and providing what I feel is a good answer.   I like sharing my knowledge and experience.

Unfortunately, I have come to the conclusion that you have to accept the fastest gun in the west problems ... everyone knows the way it works, it's just a fact. If the question is not really genuinely hard, but just requires some knowledge, someone faster will beat you to it. *Heaps* of people have the same knowledge and experience, and can likely answer faster.

So then you have to go looking at older and bounty questions.   These unfortunately are on the other side of the curve usually: they are -really- hard, and specialised.   Old not-bounty questions aren't worth answering because the original poster won't accept the answer and rarely will people upvote it.

That leaves bounty questions, which usually require not only knowledge and experience, but also investment of time and research to solve.   This is a different proposition, for someone who just enjoys sharing their knowledge and experience.

So we seem to have the strange success-driven-problem where we have too many people keen to share their knowledge and experience ... dang - our individual knowledge and experience is not worth as much as we thought, its commonplace ;)   This is coupled perhaps with not enough return on investment for time in research on truly hard problems.

One thing I will say is that I don't think the volume of bad questions plays into this.   They don't really make finding questions to answer harder.   And there is reward (rep) in cleaning them up.   I do wish that there was some disincentive for answering bad questions, so that bad questions are more discouraged, but that's a different topic.

Comment: The point about the truly hard questions being specialized, and therefore not getting enough votes, is an interesting one. Because really, there are two kinds of questions that look similar: good questions in a niche area, and mediocre questions in a popular area but too narrow to be of use to many people. The first kind definitely deserve a lot more upvotes than the second, but I can't imagine what kind of system would make that happen…

Answer (score 16):

YOLO: give up and find something more entertaining to do with your life. There's no need to continue using SO if it's just going to make you fret about most of the questions being rubbish. That's pretty much my policy nowadays, though the occasional gem does still appear.

Answer (score 13):

Your question is about two different things, and they aren't particularly related.

- Yes, the bad quality of the vast majority of questions these days is a big problem. There has been plenty of discussion about that. Ho-hum.
- Don't race. Don't concern yourself with what others do. Keep taking the time to write good answers and don't worry about anything else. If a question has been answered but not well enough, answer it better. Come back to your own answers and improve them. Be insightful. Be truthful. Be definitive. Curate helpfulness. Reputation comes not from what you do on the spur of the moment but from the legacy you leave. People will discover your good answers, or your answers on topics that turn out to affect a lot of people, over time, when you least expect it. And you'll have the satisfaction of knowing you helped point the way, years later, to people who weren't even on the site at the time you answered.

Comment: best consens so far - everyone reading this q/a has experience some things above - but your conclusion fit's best ^^

Answer (score 8):

I like answering old questions, or posting self-Q&As. I can take as much time without rushing, in hopes of other users who camp the "Active" tag will see my (possibly high quality, hard-worked and excellent) answer and upvote it. I don't like rushing answers or answering poor questions, and it's too much work for me to hunt the tabs waiting for a good question to appear.

On the other hand, sitting on the tabs are **boring**. I used to do that, but I almost stabbed myself when someone posts an exact same solution, with less explanation than mine, and I'm forced to abort my answer half-complete knowing the next group of users doing the same are probably suffering too. Soon the existing answer gets a few upvotes (proving my point) and a short discussion expands in the comments, including the explanation *somewhere* down the comment thread. It's hard to complain about the answer now that the explanation is *somewhere*, yet there's nothing interesting to add anymore.

Possibly the only person capable of providing answers of non-mediocre quality quickly would be Jon Skeet. But my skills are no where near his, so I find myself away from the tab camping.

Or, another thing you could do is to encourage OP to improve his question. If you feel that you may have an alternate solution which works, you could try leaving a comment. If other users or the OP himself finds it useful (possibly along the lines of `@Alexis That's a good idea for this use case.`) you could expand it into an answer, and address the question so it's relevant and useful. *(And upvote-worthy.)*

Bounty questions can be a good place to look for, too. Questions in the featured tab could be citing for updated information or attention to the question. This could mean that the questions has obsolete solutions (and yours may stand a chance for bounty reward and upvotes if it's helpful) or are currently not received enough attention (possibly all current answers are unhelpful and need yours :) ). They are a good place to look for technologies that you may have attempted and could shed a light. Even if it's not entirely the best solutions, if it's helpful, the bounty on the question would feature it, making the question more visible for users to browse and possibly review your answer so you get votes (both up and down) more actively.

I personally dislike the approach of posting, and editing aforehand. It's not a good practice, leaves a scratchy `"Edited \w+ ago"` signature, and bumps the thread.

Downvoting poor questions you come upon would be helpful for other users doing the same too, trying to find, attempt, answer, or help out new questions. Negative score is a strong indicator that the question does not show research effort; is unclear or not useful. By voting appropriately, you would not only be earning reputation, but helping others to earn reputation by answering the good questions as well.

Comment: If the existing answer is incomplete or poorly explained, and the author clearly has no intent in improving it, don't abandon the question. Unless editing his answer is appropriate, you should write your own. Important information shouldn't live only in comments. Yeah, maybe you won't get as much rep for the second-but-better answer as he did for the first-but-mediocre one, but you'll surely get _some_—and you'll be making the site better, which has to count for something.

Comment: I mentioned _an exact same solution_. Some code are idiomatic @abarnert, when there is nothing interesting to add since the same is already there, there is little to no incentive to adding yours.

Comment: Sure, but you say "with less explanation than mine", and "a short discussion expands in the comments, including the explanation somewhere down the comment thread". Comments aren't a substitute for a good answer (or a good question).

Comment: @abarnert: I wholeheartedly agree. With an answer properly explained, it would likely be another-another-answer-worthy. This is a really great point to note.

Comment: @abarnert I did that once. I was in "question" mode, looking for a solution to a problem I was having. I found a 3 month old self-answered question that lacked details and added a new answer. It ended up outscoring the original answer and the OP eventually swapped the accept over to my answer. That was actually quite rewarding, and I don't mean in a rep-way.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening insight @ivarni. It inspires me to take the time writing better answers from now on. Thanks!

Comment: No worries :) I don't expect things like that would happen EVERY time you do it, but at least it is a possible outcome. It does require that the question actually ends up being visited over time (ie, people come in from google) but that question is still sitting at less than 700 views and I just got another upvote less than a week ago. The front page is not where people looking for answers usually come from.

Comment: To elaborate on that, you're not answering questions to only help the OP, but for building a Q&A resource. If the question was worth answering in the first place, and the title is worded correctly then it's very likely that others will find it and come look at it and THEY are the people you're really helping. Bad questions are much less likely to draw attention because they are very often extremely specific and has a problem that is very local to the OPs codebase. Those are the questions I don't bother with any more.

Answer (score 8):

What I normally do is the following search query and then sort by "newest":

```
[tag-name] closed:no score:1.. hasaccepted:no
```

Here, an [example for jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bjquery%5D%20closed%3Ano%20score%3A1..%20hasaccepted%3Ano). See [*How do I search?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

---

Also, I had some [browser snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470711/chrome-developer-tools-what-is-snippets-support) to remove negatively voted questions from a page:

```javascript
$('.question-summary .vote-count-post').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).text(); 
    var parent = $(this).closest('.question-summary');
    if ( value.indexOf('-') !== -1)  
        parent.remove();
});
```

---

Now, as I've been playing with [userscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/userscripts), I built a small plugin to fine tune this kind of removal and just [posted it at Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/4888/filter-stack-overflow-questions) (Chrome only). The sliders will hide questions in real time:

> #### [Filter Stack Exchange questions by votes and rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/4888/filter-stack-overflow-questions)
>
> [image: script logo] *Find good questions to answer on Stack Exchange sites
>
>      filtering the questions page by score, reputation and accepted answers.*
>
> [image]

Comment: This is a really interesting UI concept. My personal preferences for questions in most tags is anything scored -1 or higher (to find stuff that could be super if edited, and quite answerable), and stuff that hasn't been answered. The _most_ interesting tend to be questions that have one or two answers that have not received any votes, but I guess that's a little harder to filter for using a script. Still, this definitely lets you drill in quickly, we might just do something similar.

Comment: @Tim, yep, the super editable -1 is indeed a nice consideration. . . . Would be great if the HTML had more meta data, making easier to play with the page. Glad to hear the news :)

Comment: I think that's the answer, right there - put more `data-` crumbs about to make it _insanely_ easy for folks to customize even more. The thing is, you sometimes _want_ to see the stuff that falls past -1, especially if the author has subsequently edited it. There are some _really_ good questions at -9 because they saw a lot of voting in the first few minutes, were fixed, but folks never came back to reevaluate their vote. That's also something we're examining in the quality initiative.

Comment: I'm revising some userscripts at Stack Apps, and folks have to do some heavy trickery to extract info from the page. I'm fixing one where nowadays the HTML contains `data-postid` and the script had to do `attr('id').replace(/\D+(\d+)/, '$1')` to get this.