# Rewarding OP redemption with attention

Tags: discussion, questions

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503295/excel-2010-chart-setsourcedata-error-1004) was originally useless, as the OP gave us no way to reproduce or diagnose the error. I downvoted and voted to close, along with at least one other user — and left a comment requesting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Amazingly, the OP heeded the call and clarified the question (and then I did some amount of editing myself) so that it's actually a good one now! It's an interesting problem, and I'm not sure I can solve it. Unfortunately, it's also way down in the feed where no one can see it.

How can we help such questions get the attention they now deserve? Both for that particular question's sake, but perhaps more importantly, as an incentive for the OPs to fix their broken questions.

Comment: Well, it gets a bump when the user provides a substantial edit, like he did.  It may not show up on the front page, but it will show up in someone's tag page.  That said, Excel and VBA are not necessarily the hottest topics.

Comment: Remove all of your down/close votes, and even upvote the question, if it fulfills all quality policies now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That doesn't address what he's actually asking about.

Comment: @Servy Editing the question already should have bumped it. Though if one really want's to get it **featured** you can apply a bounty for the question, giving away your own rep points as a reward (altruistic POV).

Comment: The `redemption-attention` badge !!

Comment: @Coffee: Nice idea. A badge for bountying a someone else's poster-edited question, if it moves (while under bounty) from at least negative 2 to at least positive 2 (without regard to your own vote). (Should be gold)

Comment: This difficulty in rounding up enough votes to undo the damage is *precisely* why (frequent *unwise* advice from the usual suspects to the contrary) your first instinct should not be to *close* a question, but rather simply to *request* what you feel would make it answerable with a comment.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I'm not sure I agree. The entire purpose of the put-on-hold system is to drive questions to improvement. If the put-on-hold system is not accomplishing that (because the questions, once improved, die anyway), then I think it would be better to improve that system, rather than advising people to avoid it.

Comment: This is another example of how the legitimate desire "to express displeasure" with the state of the question, ends up having a lingering, counterproductive effect of acting as an answer ban, even once the question is answerable.  The responder ends up having to recruit a re-open lobby before they can answer the question they've gotten improved.  **So much simpler to just leave a comment, and answer if and *immediately* when improvements make such appropriate**.

Comment: "the damage" *should* have an effect of training posters to post high-quality questions *in the first place*.  They should learn, when their question is relegated to obscurity, that they should have done a better job up-front.  It's not wise to allow sloppy behavior and then task the community with coaxing posters to improve their questions. Yes, that avenue *does exist*, but it's *not* the preferred avenue.  The preferred avenue is to get high-quality content from the get-go, and site behaviors that encourage this are good, IMHO.  -- from yours truly, a usual suspect.

Comment: @RobertCrovella - "they" are not a single entity who can learn, they are a flood of new, unique instances.  But "you" - who persist in believing in the flawed close-to-fix idea are here long enough, and see enough, that **you** actually could learn from your mistake.

Comment: I disagree.  They can learn, whoever they are.  The expectations of the site are pretty clear.  It's niether unwise, nor a mistake, to enforce them.   I knew almost nothing about SO when I started.  I learned plenty, including from my own mistakes.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't disagree with you, If I see a problem (unless its just ridiculously major) with a post and its very new, I'll leave a comment; wait a few (around 10) minutes, then downvote/VTC after that if I get no response. Even doing that >90% of questions have no activity, and I (like most people) probably aren't going to wait hours with the question open hoping the asker comes back; we moderate, and hope they improve.

Comment: This does not just affect bad questions.  I've had questions get lost in the feed because I only tagged them with a very specific tag, then thought better of it and added a more general tag just a few minutes later.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede That will bump it to the top, and you should at least still be at 0 score. The problem here is that closed questions need 5 reopen votes and often have negative scores, which users can tend to avoid.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I decide on the spot whether to downvote / vote to close based on the current quality of the question. Those votes can be undone later if justified. Why do that instead of just not voting in the first place? It's a question of estimated probabilities. From my observations, it's much more likely that a question will stay the same (i.e. continue to be deserving of the down/close votes and subsequent garbage collection) rather than improve. What breaks the system is that life is too short: people (incl me) rarely return to the question later to correct their votes (or non-votes).

Comment: How about deleting the question and creating a new one with all the information.

Comment: **..an incentive for the OPs to fix their broken questions.** seems very wrong. Why would anyone want to give incentive? They shouldn't have posted broken questions in the first place. Usually a 1 or 2 comments from community are enough for a decent question-poster to clarify them which takes few minutes at most. In that case, it's *still* a fresh question and gets enough attention. If anyone cares enough for older questions (either OP or anyone) then they can offer a bounty. This is basically *incentives for poor-at-first questions* which doesn't seem to encourage good questions to boot.

Comment: ah, very sneaky self-promotion, OP >:)

Comment: @CarrieKendall: I posted this meta question one day *before* posting an answer to that SO question. So, no, I didn't use a meta post to promote my as of then not-yet-existing answer, if that's what you're implying. Just setting the record straight in case anyone gets the wrong idea :-)

Comment: "How can we help ... questions get ... attention"?  Offer a bounty

Answer (score 14):

Two options:

1. **Do nothing.** The question gets a bump when the user provides a substantial edit. It may not show up on the front page, but it will show up in someone's tag page.
2. If you really want to get it featured, then **offer a bounty** on the question.

Comment: That said, Excel and VBA are not necessarily the hottest topics. –  Robert Harvey♦ 18 hours ago

Comment: it doesn't matter if the tags are popular or not.. there are always some experts in even less popular tags willing to help - they just need to get notified somehow so a bounty seems like a good solution.

Comment: 3. The Meta effect ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's a third option: bring attention to the question in the chat rooms.

The chat rooms have their own process and tags dedicated for this sort of thing. For example, when someone wants to gather a posse to close a question, they post a message and add `[tag:cv-pls]` to the message (*"cv-pls"* is shorthand for "close vote please"). I'm told its a fair and balanced system, so there should be a `[tag:uv-pls]` tag, too (with *"uv-pls"* being "up vote please").

You can read more about using the chat rooms to enlist the posse at [Remove cv-pls tag from chat rooms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271899/608639).

Comment: Note: there is the `[tag:rov-pls]` tag i.e. reopen vote please, which can be used if the question was closed but deserves reopening.