# What makes a spectacular answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, upvotes, gamification

I've been using (*playing*) Stack Overflow for almost two years now. I love the community and I love the gamification aspect. I love the fact that Stack Overflow tries to reward it's users for being helpful and useful contributers. Through the use of Stack Overflow, I have become a much better coder. I still regularly glance through my Badges section to see "what can I do to help, that will get me super special internet points / badges?".

I am having particular trouble with the answering-related badges. So far, despite relatively regular contribution, even the "Nice Answer" badge still eludes me.

So, what makes the difference between a decent answer and a Nice Answer™? Or a Nice Answer and a Good Answer? Or alternatively, what can I do to raise the quality/profile of my answers, make them hit home harder, and make them more widely useful or interesting?

Comment: It seems to be random to me. I would try finding questions that likely have broad appeal so you get the requisite number of views to get the badge. Unfortunately, that usually means staying out of niche topics (if thats your usual area of posting).

Comment: Concise, complete, comprehensible.

Comment: [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271017/839601)

Comment: It's the will of the people. The only question I've gotten a [Nice Answer on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917641/java-calendar-returns-wrong-week/25918745#25918745) provides no practical value other than demonstrating why something isn't working as it appeared to be intended.

Comment: A big part of it is the types of questions that you decide to answer. Looking through your recent answers, most of the questions are not of high quality - which people tend to avoid. So if nobody sees your answer, you won't get upvotes. To make things even worse, you're also in one of the more unfortunate tags: [tag:android].

Comment: Also, make sure your answer is not a bore to read. Answers that I've read with high scores all bring the question down to earth to be understandable, even to those who are may not be familiar with the roots of the question. Don't belittle the audience, of course, just bring it down into understandable and non-technical terms if possible.

Comment: Another point - This only borders partially on gamification. The badge is nice, but a true Nice Answer may sit at few votes for a long time because it's hard to stumble upon. You should focus foremost on the quality on the answer when answering, not how many upvotes you hope to get out of it.

Comment: I have 3 Nice Answer badges and didn't even trie to get it. Then again, it has been awarded almost half a million times so it seems nothing particular. My bronze C badge is one of only 1,290, and that makes me feel much better!

Comment: Never hope for a hole in one, it is entirely too rare.  By far the most important aspects are patience and a good question.  An answer can take *years* to get enough votes.  And Google has to find it, people search questions, not answers

Comment: Congratulations on a meta Nice Question™ badge!

Comment: I didn't get a nice answer badge til over 20k.  It's just the way of the SO world.  On the other hand, I have like 8 nice question badges so it's pretty obvious what I'm better at.  Like you, my programming has also improved dramatically since I joined SO.

Comment: Frustratingly, I have one answer that is only 2 votes away from great. Grrrr.

Comment: the majority of my "Nice Answer" badges came from questions that have been around for years, and it's usually on answers that i wouldn't consider to be the hardest to come up with or my best answers. Instead, it's on questions that beginner developers commonly search for.

Comment: Saw a question today "Why doesn't html,body{height:100%} work?", and answered the specific question with the correct answer, but keep getting down-voted because I didn't add "Doing it this way will mess up your design, though," or avoiding his question all together by saying something like "No, no, no, you should do it like this instead." Don't really see the point in answering when people think that subjective answers are more constructive than objective ones, but all I can do is either ignore it or stop answering people's questions.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Certain tags attract more highly voted answers than others and as pointed out in the comment thread, [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) is *not* a high-voting environment.

### Great answers are the ones that continue to help future readers

It is difficult to get +10 an any one answer, even in a high-voting tag, ***right after posting it***.

However, don't worry about getting those badges now. **Worry about making good and lasting enough answers** that will earn those badges **later**. I have ~3500 answers and not a week goes by these days where I don't earn 2 or 3 Nice Answer and Enlightened badges from old answers that had enduring usefulness.  People encounter them, find them useful, and upvote them.

I remember in my first year feeling like you do, wondering when I'll ever earn those badges. Then I remember the first time I did - it was on a SQL question where all I did was point out to the OP that the keyword `UPDATE` was misspelled as `UDPATE`.  The votes poured in as users took it as an opportunity to deride the OP for making a simple "code blindness" mistake, and I didn't feel especially accomplished for it. That really stuck with me.

Now, I can see my contributions as lasting and permanently useful. That's what I would encourage you to aim for --  a portfolio of well explained, documented, and provably working answers that will have life beyond the OP's initial problem.

Comment: spectacular answer! ;)

Comment: +1 for the "right after posting it". One of my nice answer badges was awarded 2.5 years after posting it. Patience, young developer :-)

Comment: *point out to the OP that the keyword UPDATE was misspelled as UDPATE* ... That's because anyone reading it (even with the most basic knowledge) can verify that this is the correct answer; for longer & more complicated answers, this is usually not the case, since you need to understand the question (not always easy for difficult questions), understand the answer given, *and* be reasonably sure this is actually the correct answer ... This is why simple questions often get more upvotes right away... :-/

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Exactly. Coupled with the fact that, although I answered it in a lighthearted and humorous way at the time, others saw it as an opportunity for derision of the OP. Those "look what a silly mistake the OP made" answers tend to attract votes too.

Comment: +1 nice answer, concise, useful, helpful, answers the question

Comment: Just what I was going to say except that you said it better. Grrr. You are absolutely right. About 5 of my answers have turned out to be high-scoring and I would never have guessed that _any_ of them would have such staying power. See also the second bullet point in my answer here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271754/341994

Comment: Plus, you just taught me that hats are adjustable. Grrr again.

Answer (score 41):

At the beginning it was very frustrating seeing questions such as:

> 2 + 2 = ?

having hundreds of upvotes when I was receiving (rarely) 1 or 2 votes for much harder questions like:

> 5 * 8 = ?

Neither playing fastest gun nor providing long answers to old questions brought me any badge.

Ironically my best scored (9 votes) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26626348/4186297) is one-liner which took me 2 minutes.
As opposed my 3-page essay [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27337754/4186297) took me half a day to complete and provided no votes.

So just write good answers and be patient and you don't know the day when you will be rewarded.

**EDIT:**

When I was writing this post two days ago I supposed that several people would read it. I hoped that some of them will follow the link and that I will receive maybe 1 or 2 votes. But I have 25 upvotes now and answer was accepted today. I also received 5 voted for my Scala question and 6 badges (3 of them on meta). This thread on meta turned out to be a lift to heaven (not only for my questions). This thread is about (un)justice, (un)fairness and (un)luck. I had a lot of luck last two days and gained a lot. But is it fair? It would be a good subject for other essay.

Thank you for votes. I am still stunned. It assured me that writing carefully prepared answer (even  to old question) has more sense than solving someone's homework in a hurry.

Comment: For reasons unbeknownst to me, that experience seems to be the rule rather than the exception.

Comment: Try "15 = ? * ?". It has potential =D. Sorry, I had to, I loved your examples.

Comment: A lot of the answers that I worked hard on languish unloved (or, at least, un-upvoted) while a number of those that I didn't work hard on have scored well.  Some scored fairly well immediately; others scored well after some revisions.  Many have taken years to get the credit; I still get the occasional 'nice answer' badge for answers provided 5+ years ago.

Comment: The long thorough answers tend to score better if you already have a high rep. A long answer requires people to work (i.e. read words and think) to decide if it is good; that work is more likely to be done if you already appear to know what you're doing; you're also likely to get "they must be right" upvotes if you already have high rep (I however tend to be far more critical of a high rep user than a low rep one). The longer reference material style answers seem to gather votes over time rather than all at once whereas neato short answers get one hit and then fade into obscurity.

Comment: @luk32 I don't even try to answer such difficult questions as "15 = ? * ?". I am not at this level yet.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Why unbeknownst? Imagine Joe Lambda reading StackOverflow, he reads a tough question... partway, and move on. Too difficult. Then he reads an easy question, and an easy answer he understands, he can see that the answer is correct, so upvote! Therefore, simple answers to easy questions are bound to attract more votes, simply because they are more *accessible* (they have a higher conversion rate).

Comment: My highest answers have 'felt easy'. The posts that have taken some effort or research have fallen on deaf ears. Part of that's tags, part of that's audience, and part of that is just random luck. Answering a broadly useful question, (and doing so well)  and thenpeople find later seems to be the trick.

Comment: [This single, rather esoteric question](http://superuser.com/q/792607/349115) has got me more rep than all of my answers on Stack Overflow combined including lengthy answers explaining things in depth with screenshots all the way through such as [this answer about how to normalise out a database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27405307/2291321) that has no upvotes at all. Life really isn't fair.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It makes sense of course, it just seems so *backwards*.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR In all fairness, that was an *awesome* question :) Kudos for even noticing that you had a toaster-keyboard.

Comment: mystically, the essay you linked is now +10 and rising ;)

Comment: @luk32 closed as primarily opinion based ;)

Comment: -1 for factual errors.  The essay linked has at least 23 upvotes, not zero.  (I am kidding)

Comment: @ydaetskcoR At least it's not a typewriter ...

Comment: @Yakk I wasn't prepared. I should have several 0-scored essays and swap links everyday.

Answer (score 26):

I'd say there are a few qualities of a *spectacular* answer (I'd say this differs from getting the [Nice Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258) badge as [@Matt Coubrough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280441/497356) points out):

## It belongs to a popular tag

*(or it's a question lots of people have)*

There are many fantastic answers on Stack Overflow, but unless your answer is about something that lots of people care about, you just aren't going to get the page views and therefore the upvotes that answers in a popular tag will get. This might seem unfair, but that's the way the site works, for good or for ill.

## It's well written

Sometimes all that separates an "ok" answer from a great one is that the great one explained things a tiny bit better or maybe included some code (that works and is also well written).

This sometimes means focusing less on speed and more on quality, especially if you're certain you can post a better answer, taking advantage of that small quality gap. You may even miss the "accepted" checkmark, but don't hesitate to post an answer that you believe is better, even after another answer has been accepted.

## It's canonical

When you search "How do I Foo the Bar in BazSharpPlus", if the top search result is a Stack Overflow answer and that is *the* way to Foo the Bar, you can bet that answer will have lots of upvotes. This requires answering questions that don't already have answers on the Internet, or if they do, they are hard to uncover.

## It's old

In Internet time that is. As others have pointed out, it can take some time for your posts to get upvoted. The longer it's around and the more people that it helps, the more upvotes it's going to get.

## *Cheesy side note*

Fake Internet points aside, as long as you're helping people and contributing positively, that's the most important part. If you do this well, the badges and reputation will come.

Answer (score 23):

A **Nice answer badge** usually seems to be awarded for being the *quickest* to point out something that *many* people can recognise *easily* as being the *correct* solution to a question in a popular tag that isn't so low quality that it gets deleted.

This may simply be because questions get buried so quickly now. A canonical answer to a common programming problem is also going to score highly, however there are fewer and fewer common programming problems that lack canonical answers on Stack Overflow.

The quick and correct answer that scores a Nice Answer badge may diverge from what *actually* constitutes a *"nice answer"*, which in my opinion is an answer of utility to many, that is clear, concise, shows examples, actually has a didactic purpose (as opposed to just showing the code that fixes the problem) and possibly also links to relevant official reference material to support the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Essentially, you have to answer *popular* questions and either:

1. do so better than all the existing answers, or
2. do at least as well as all the other answers, and be one of the first answers, so that you get accepted

The *popular* bit is important. Even the most highly-upvoted answer on the site has a ratio of 38 views per vote. If you're answering questions that only get a few hundred views *ever*, then you're putting a serious cap on how many votes your answer can hope to get.

So how do we find popular questions to answer, and provide answers to them that will draw upvotes?

One approach to this would be to watch as questions get posted, try to identify questions that will become popular as they arrive, and then play and win a game of [Fastest Gun In The West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). This has never been my way, and I am poorly equipped to advise you if you take this approach.

The *other* approach is to stumble across *old* questions that have not been answered or have been answered inadequately, and then answer them better.

The downside of this approach is that you don't merely need to provide an adequate answer to a question when it gets posted, you need to provide a *significantly better answer than anyone else's, after other people have had the chance to answer*.

But if you are a full-time professional programmer (or, I suppose, a full-time amateur programmer, if such creatures exist), then this approach gives you an enormous advantage, which is that you don't need to expend any effort at all to *find questions to answer*. Instead, you simply wait until the following happens:

- You are at work one day, and you need to Frobnicate a Widget in FooScript++.
- Guessing correctly that this must be a common problem, you Google for "frobnicate a widget in fooscript++" and find a clearly written Stack Overflow question entitled "How can I Frobincate a Widget in FooScript++?" with thousands of views.
- To your dismay, all the answers suck and were written by gibbering morons! (Or perhaps the answers look superficially reasonable, but when you actually try to use them they don't quite work, and you discover a layer of complexity to the problem of Frobnicating Widgets that the original answerers didn't spot or understand.)

Now is your chance! Even if you don't have a chance to solve the problem at work, add it to your Favourites list so that you can return to it later. Now you have a problem to solve that:

- You already know attracts large numbers of readers
- Nobody has yet answered adequately
- Is in your area of expertise
- Is actually directly relevant to a problem you need to solve for whatever project you're working on

Solve it and answer. You will make the internet a better place and earn shiny badges! And - if you are like me - you will earn infinitely more satisfaction knowing that your answer is being read by tens of thousands of people than you ever would have answering questions with a couple of hundred views that will most likely go into a pit to die once they scroll off the homepage.

My two highest-upvoted answers both came about via the process described above. Note, by the way, that you'll sometimes find popular questions that are terribly answered in the strangest of places, and they needn't be mind-bendingly difficult to solve. My [second-highest upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17931752/1709587) is about finding method references in a freaking IDE, and was posted 2 years after the question - but nonetheless has risen to the top, is on 81 votes and gradually climbing. The reason I was able to do this was simply that, after many thousands of views, nobody else had posted an answer that didn't suck. Spotting low-hanging fruit like this is great if you want to nab yourself a Great Answer badge.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. I've added answers to a couple of historic android questions where a much simpler solution exists, and they've already gotten me decent amounts of votes. There is a lot more patience to this method which comes back to answers accumulating votes over time. I think people generally shy away from answering historic questions because of the lack of immediate feedback/reward.

Comment: Yes, [sometimes this indeed works well](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/installing-raspbian-from-noobs-without-display/19928) (though I don't know if it has many views).

Answer (score 10):

Luck.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element/8716680#8716680) to a canonical javascript question, as of today:

- Posted: 1,079 days ago (nearly three years)
- Views: ~55,111 (20,346 on the current question and 34,765 on [the question from which it was migrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716655/simple-jquery-click-not-working?lq=1))
- Score: 106

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234480/can-i-color-table-columns-using-css-without-coloring-individual-cells/27234542#27234542) to a simple question regarding html column coloring, as of today:

- Posted: 16 days ago
- Views: 2,442
- Score: 108

I make an effort to curate my collection of answers -updating them to ensure that they're accurate, readable, and useful. That first answer has been edited 40 times and has slowly and steadily accrued votes over a three year period. The second answer, which took far less effort or expertise, scored more votes than the other in **1.48%** of the time with **4.43 %** of the views.

You can post a truly great answer and watch it languish for months without any attention... or you can have an embarrassing, shoot-from-the-hip answer earn a ridiculous amount of votes.

I could list ten different factors which can affect the votes, but mostly it seems to be luck.

Comment: Holy Christ, 100 upvotes within the first 5 days of posting? That's the power of the Hot Network Questions section, right there!

Comment: The answer was solid and useful, the luck factor of getting into the Hot Network Questions section notwithstanding. Now, how to get questions *I'm* answering onto there...?

Comment: "Ten different factors" ... one of them is that editing an answer brings the question back onto the main page, where it may be spotted by casual front page readers. (I certainly don't want to say you should not update your answers! Anyway, those same casual readers have a chance to *downvote* as well -- which, apparently, they do not.)

Comment: What the hell... I saw that questions 16 days ago, I was typing the very same answer while you posted it.. So I skipped it with an upvote... I should've posted it regardless!!!

Comment: [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/109982/most-recent-posts-that-reached-a-score-of-x-in-the-first-y-days) gives an idea of how rare it is for a post to get a lot of votes early on.

Answer (score 8):

## What makes a spectacular answer is the one which solves the problem.

Badges and Reputation gives you good feel, but don't go behind that, just keep on answering. It'll improve your quality of answers day by day and a day will come when you'll receive reps/badges without any efforts taken. It's always a slow start initially but it will take speed once you answer more than 500. Your old answer will keep on giving you reps every day.

## TIP:

- Don't answer just a link.
- Give code with the explanation. Just writing the code will solve this problem but giving explanation will increase it's quality.
- Explain in a way that non english user is able to understand. SO have very diverse audience.

Keep helping and keep enjoying.

Answer (score 6):

Bearing in mind that so many page views come to Stack Overflow via search engines and not by people going to the SO home page and browsing, it's important to do a little Search Engine Optimization on your answer, and especially on the question, so that future people who have the problem will be able to find it. This will be the difference between the question containing your spectacular answer coming up first in search results or being buried several pages deep.

I often write up an answer to a question that's confusing or poorly worded, and take some time to edit the question to make it more clear. I give it a good title that describes the problem, which is important especially because the asker may not have understood the problem well enough to give it a proper title. I fix misspellings, clean up code formatting, and try to make it helpful to other searchers.

This is oh-so-important for questions about a specific error message; how many times have you gotten a strange compiler error, Googled for it, and have gotten a SO question as the first result? If that question looks clear and descriptive and relevant from the Google results page, it will earn a clickthrough and maybe an upvote.

The SO developers have realized that answering + editing is an important way to contribute to the site, and have recently added badges to encourage the behavior, so try to earn them!

Answer (score 3):

**!(Bad answers)**

Which is too abstract to be useful. So instead, I'll use a white-list approach to answering.

**Precursor:**

- The author has completely read and understood the question at hand. This step doesn't happen often enough.
- The author actually has the ability to answer the question

**The Actual Answer:**

- The GIST of the solution is summarized at the beginning of the answer in a short sentence or code example.
- The answer comprehensively lists out the explanation in clear detail thereafter
- Inline examples are abound
- External references are listed as well, but they are an adjunct to the content on the page
- Appropriate usage of formatting is much appreciated for clear communication
- The answer has not more or not less the amount of required explanation
- The author is polite and courteous
- The answer continues to endure in its usefulness

**POST Answer**

- The author is polite and courteous in comments and corrections
- The author regularly updates the answer to keep it relevant

**But All Is For NOT**

All of this is a [load of dingo's kidneys](http://www.whysanity.net/monos/hikers.html) as votes only matter in terms of what a good answer really is. Come on. You've read this far thinking the other stuff mattered? Ha ha ha ha ha ha ha....ha ha ha. *cough* ... moo ha ha ha ha. *ahem* ...

Comment: Is _"all is for not"_ a tongue-in-cheek jest or did you mean _"naught"_?

Comment: NOT meaning this is the opposite. Yes. you got it. That's why you got the big rep, son.

Answer (score 3):

I reviewed several of my "Nice Answers."

- Most are on questions that probably should have been closed as too subjective.  (To be fair, most of those questions are very old, before subjectivity became a major close priority.)  Subjective questions often have lots of viewers.
- Most are on questions that got *lots* of answers (and thus lots of viewers).
- Most are not the highest voted answer nor the accepted answer.  Often, it's not even close.
- Most are answers that have been around a long time (and thus have had lots of viewers over time).
- Most are on reasonable questions.  Poor questions get fewer viewers and thus lower answer scores.  Editing a question to improve it can help your score because it gets more viewers.  But, more importantly, an improved question is more likely to be helpful to others in the future.
- Some are answers that I've revised many times in attempt to make them better.  Revising has the side effect of exposing it to new viewers.
- About half of my highest scoring answers (regardless of the "Nice Answer" badge) are not the accepted answer.

I don't shoot for "Nice Answer."  I shoot for providing the most helpful answer I can come up with.  Rep is nice, but I don't believe I'm motivated (much) by the game aspect.  StackOverflow is helpful to me, and I like to give back.

Answer (score 3):

- *An answer*
  Simple resolution of issue depicted with no explanation.
- *A nice answer*
  Simple resolution of issue depicted with a simple explanation of OP's situation.
- *A good answer*
  Robust resolution of issue depicted with a simple explanation of OP's situation.
- *A great answer*
  Robust resolution of issue depicted with a robust explanation of OP's situation.
- *A spectacular answer*
  Robust resolution of issue depicted with a robust explanation of OP's situation as well as an explanation of the underlying broader issue of the OP's situation.

Often the first aspect of an answer is to directly address the issue raised by the OP. After all, they are going to be the immediate beneficiary of the answer. Helping them resolve their issue is usually the best first order of business to solve.

Once the resolution is shown, it really helps to explain to the OP why it was used and what about using it actually solves the problem. This will help both the OP and other users in understanding the significance of the solution.

After a solid solution and explanation for the OP it is important to consider the broader audience of the answer. Consider the tags used, the title, and the culture of the technology. Address this audience with an expansion of the why. Include possible advantages or disadvantages, the topicality of your solution (how this example is a resolution of the overall issue), solvency (the viability of actually using the shown solution in a broader sense beyond the OP's situation), and the inheritance (is this solution already a common practice or best practice).

Doing this takes time, and often if you write all of this up, take some time to make a masterpiece of your answer, then post it, the possibility of it being buried under the simple resolution with no explanation is high.

As a result, there is a little bit of strategy which can also help in posting one of these answers if the question was just asked. The first order of business should be to start with a good answer. Find the robust resolution to the OP's issue, write up a simple explanation, and post it so that your answer is viewed along with the simple resolution and no explanation set to make it stand out. Next, enhance your explanation of the situation with regards to your resolution for the OP in an edit and post that. Lastly, fill in the section which addresses future visitors, and both how your resolution applies to the current situation
and fits in to the situation as it is currently used in common practice.