# How can I find questions on what I am good at?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to help others when I'm free. But I'm confused when I see all the questions show together before me. Doesn't it have a classification? How can I find questions I want?
Thanks!

Comment: Type the tag you feel you can help with in the search bar. If you feel you are skilled at python search “python”.

Comment: I do the opposite way: every day, I view the questions, and click `ignore tag` when I don't know about the tag. Questions with ignored tag will not show up in home page. After some 10 days, I will see more relevant questions in home page.

Comment: I don't search out questions to answer. As I'm programming, I use stackoverflow to 'look up' how others are completing a similar task. As I successfully complete my own task, I add knowledge to stackoverflow where it's missing.

Comment: Also, in case it's not obvious, you don't gain (or lose!) reputation from Meta sites, except meta.stackexchange.com. The rep you see on the Meta sites is your rep on the main sites (so in this case, we see your stackoverflow.com rep because this is Stack Overflow's Meta site). **Further reading:** https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta and https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: One more thing that's worth mentioning: votes are voting on the _content_ of the post, _not_ the author! That's a very important distinction. Because you're new here you'll probably make mistakes to begin with and your question or answers may get downvoted.... don't take it personally! The downvotes simply indicate that there's something wrong with your post. Usually people won't tell you what's wrong so you just have to guess. A good place to start is _be specific_, and include as much relevant information as possible (whether it's a question or an answer).

Comment: I answered across on that duplicate suggestion a few years back, still seems applicable: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271706/57475

Answer (score 55):

First, **identify** which **tags** (fields) you are good and bad in.

For example, I'm good in Firebase but I got no experience in Firebase Cloud Function.

Then, **search** the tag you preferred and ignore the tag you are bad in by:

1. preferred: **`[tag]`**
2. ignore: **`-[tag]`**

Example:

[image]

You will now have all the questions related to firebase but not firebase-cloud-functions.  Browse through the questions, are they what you want?

**YES**? Add the preferred tags to your watched tags!

**NO**? Add them to your Ignored Tags!

So, next time when you enter [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), stackoverflow will show all your interested tags at your first glance and ignore the one you don't want to!

**ADVANCED SEARCH TIPS**

-suggested by **rene**

Once you are familiar with the tags searching, you can now search the related posts that are not answered by the community!

To find post that has no answer: `answers:0`

Post that is still open: `closed:no`

[image]

For more advanced searching, you could refer the image below.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Using the tag search has the benefit you can also add some advanced search options like `score:2` and/or `closed:no` `answers:0` to get questions that are likely to be reasonable.

Comment: Thanks again. But can we use wildcard in the tag, just like "dynamics*"?

Comment: yes, by adding asterisk (*) for e.g. [firebase*], it will return firebase-cloud-messaging ........ etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. "()" or "[]"? Can I add it to ignore list?

Comment: SORRRY! TYPO! yes, by adding asterisk *  within the tagging [ ] for e.g. [firebase*], it will return firebase-cloud-messaging ........ etc.

Comment: I have filled "Watched Tags" and "Ignored Tags" with some keywords. But all the questions, no matter in Interesting or Featured, don't have the keywords in the Watched Tags! Surely they don't have those keywords in Ignored Tags. Why is this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too many questions from me! Another one: How can I say "Thank you" to rene or Angus Tay individually here?

Comment: I realised that happen recently (not sure it is intended or just bug), so usually, I just click on the tag, typing manually, (face palm), to reply to someone , at the beginning of the comment, put @, and type their name

Comment: @FengyongJia When you comment on someone's question or answer, that person will automatically be notified. If you want to reply to someone else's comment, use the @ symbol, like this: `@rene Thanks for the help!`

Comment: @FengyongJia Upvote the corresponding post. Don't write thanks comments, they will be removed. Even on meta (I think).

Comment: @FengyongJia also a good way (here and in the main page) of thanking someone who helped you solve your question is accepting their answer as valid!

Answer (score 6):

All questions have one or more tags at the bottom that describe what they are about. According to the [searching help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), you search for tags by placing it in square brackets. For example, if you wanted to search for questions tagged with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) you could put `[php]` into the search bar.

If you know a lot about a tag, clicking the "Watch Tag" button at the top of the search page will highlight those questions on the home page. Similarly, clicking the "Ignore Tag" button hides it from your home page.

---

You can get a searchable list of all tags at https://stackoverflow.com/tags or by clicking the "Tags" link in the left sidebar.

Answer (score 6):

Filter search is helpful too.

[Here's a filtered search](https://stackexchange.com/filters/336233/all-c) I use that shows me all questions tagged with `clojure` or `clojurescript`, across the entire network. I don't even need to pick what SE site I want to limit it to, which has lead to a couple interesting answer opportunities.

I have this as one of my home tabs that show up when I start my browser. You could broaden it and create your own combined filtered version of Stack Overflow's homepage if you wanted to.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that existed. And it looks like that link isn't private :)

Comment: @AndréKool Ya, I randomly found it by poking around my profile. It's great. Especially if you're into a subject that exists on multiple sites. I can get code review, stack Overflow, and stuff from the other sites in one Clojure feed.