# Migrated question doesn't show new contributor indicator

Tags: bug, migrated-questions, new-contributor-indicator

A few days ago, [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373321/how-can-i-find-questions-on-what-i-am-good-at?cb=1) was migrated from Stack Overflow to Meta. The question was posted by a user with one reputation, and a brand new member at the time (3 days at the time of writing this) on both MSO and Stack Overflow. However, on the migrated question on MSO, there was no new contributor indicator.

[image]

Comment: Probably because the user doesn't have reputation on meta.

Comment: @user202729 but isn't that more of a reason to show the new contributor badge?

Comment: @Script47: New contributor is shown on date-time of first post; not on reputation. May be that user already have posted earlier but no rep gain. I cannot verify though; just guess.

Comment: @AmitJoshi as specified in my post, the user had been a member of the site for _three_ days (and the question was posted two days prior, so one day), so it's unlikely that by the time this was posted, he'd already been on the site for a week.