# feature to group your favorite questions?

Tags: feature-request

I would like to to have the following ability, I think it would help uses to filter and find their required favorite questions a lot faster.

as a user I would like to be able to group my favorite questions(the questions that I have starred) using custom tags.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit, it's not clear what you're requesting with this? Are you talking about [http://stackoverflow.com/users/974876/xerxes?tab=favorites](your Favourited questions), or questions that you might be interested in?

Comment: @Tanner the questions that I have starred

Comment: @Xerxes : Any update on this feature? Its really a useful one.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter your favourites in the search field like so:

### [Your Favourites](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20infavorites:974876)

You can add tags to the search if required:

### [Your Favourites With Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A974876%20%5Bjavascript%5D)

You can also include search terms:

### [Your Favourites With Tag & Search Term](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A974876%20%5Bjavascript%5D%20script)

I recently asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search) to expose some of this functionality.