# A list of my questions without an accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, questions, profile-page

Sometimes questions are asked that get answers so late that I kind of forget that I asked them. Maybe I found the solution later on my own and forgot to add an answer myself, maybe the problem disappeared because I moved to a different project, etc, etc.

I don't like leaving questions unanswered, and it's not good when people do add answers and they are never accepted.

Would it be possible to add a page on our profiles that list all our questions that does not have an accepted answer yet? And maybe somehow nudge us once in a while (without getting annoying) to have a look and see if there are any that has gotten valid answers that could be accepted or if I can add a solution myself?

Comment: While it requires some work, you can go through the questions list on your profile, every question where the *x answers* is white does not have an accepted answer. When it's yellow, it does have an accepted answer.

Comment: @Stijn That I was already aware of, but that's quite a bit of pain when there more than a handful questions.

Comment: I noticed, just hours ago, that I had some good answers to my questions, which I should have accepted ages ago. I ended up manually going through the list of all questions I've ever asked, which was fine because there are only ten, but something more sophisticated would have been welcome.

Comment: For help with the advanced search, check out my question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search. Here's a saved version of the search for your criteria: http://jsfiddle.net/4qzfa9ft/7/

Comment: I would love to have this feature. It will be a time-saver and will improve usability. We can even create a small widget in the right column, that will show number of unaccepted questions with ability to click on it and go to the list of all unaccepted questions. I would also love to see a widget with the list of my latest questions and answers, so I will be able to quickly navigate to them. Right now, I have to create a bookmark for every question in my browser and to manually handle them. I will be glad to create some mock-ups to demonstrate the idea if it will help.

Answer (score 114):

You can do this using advanced search terms:

> [user:me hasaccepted:no answers:1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1)

This should show you questions you asked, which have at least one answer, but which don't have an accepted answer.

Comment: Not particularly discoverable, but works for me :P

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching for a full list. It's full of magic and wonder and unicorns.

Comment: You certainly want more than one answer too: `user:me hasaccepted:no answers:1..`

Comment: Actually, `answers:1`,`score:1` etc. by themselves return posts including 1+ (interestingly, `score:-1` returns posts with score -1 and above).

Comment: A clickable link for the lazy: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1.. wherein I noticed that you have to do the search for each SO site.

Comment: This should be added as a link in the account page titled "My Unanswered Questions"

Comment: @BAR Don't you mean titled "Answered But Not Accepted"? Regardless of the wording, I'm all for prompting users to review answers they've received but have been neglecting.

Answer (score 2):

Every time someone answers a question that you asked, it sends you a notification that is visible (bright red) on the top bar. That is the nudge you are looking for.

Comment: That is a good nudge, however I'm not always able to react to it right then and there.

Comment: @Svish The notification will remain until you click on it.