# Reminder to accept my own answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, self-answer

Answering your own question, Q&A style, [is explicitly encouraged](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). For [perfectly good reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277960/why-cant-you-accept-your-own-answer-immediately), you can accept your own answer only after 2 days.

When I come back to the question and try to accept it, I often see:

[image]

Should we remind users to accept their own answer when it's possible, assuming there are no other answers to the question?

Leaving it as-is generates unaccepted questions for no good reason.

Comment: I don't think it worth doing that, especially because users don't answer their own questions on a daily bases. When someone answers his own question, he'll probably remember that because this doesn't happen a lot.

Comment: I have a good number of self-answered Q&As already and I *still* routinely forget to accept my own answers after 2 days. It doesn't take too long for me to remember, though... I usually return to them for the first week or so after posting them (because they're *special*).

Comment: @MarounMaroun Perhaps some do. I definitely don't remember to go back to old questions and accept my own answers, especially when there's a weekend in between.

Comment: @BoltClock So let's have a nice reminder - could be after a week, not just 3 days. It would just serve as a parallel mechanism to the one that lets the OP know there's a new answer to view or accept.

Comment: IMO waiting a week actually seems like a pretty good timeframe for accepting self-answers. Give other people the chance to pitch in anyway and give yourself the time to let it hang and dry on the clothing line. It isn't exactly uncommon for me that I think I have a solution and then later it turns out it was incomplete, or still entirely wrong because I had tunnel vision.

Comment: I have not checked if this has already been discussed, but you could make it more general. A week or so after a user asks a question with no accepted answers, they would receive a notification: "Did any of these answers answer your question?".

Comment: @Jack I beg to differ. Regular answers (not by the asker) generate an alert, and the OP can read an accept. Another reminder would trash the inbox, and incentivize users not to accept answers right away. Answers the asker generate no reminders at all.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question, you just reminded me to go back and accept a weeks old self answer :-)

Comment: I tend to leave that question open in a separate browser tab. Awkward but usually effective. It would be nice if the system would auto-accept a self-answered question with no other answers after 2 days, or show a reminder in the Inbox if there are other answers to consider.

Comment: @AdamMatan: For the case where there is another answer, sure. I don't think even one of my self-answered questions received a second answer. No idea if that's a general trend or my questions aren't attracting views.

Comment: I like the idea of a reminder, but not auto-accept.  Many times the only answer is an attempt by the OP to edit the question, [for example...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162059/android-sliding-fragment-how-to-link-a-controller-class-to-a-view)

Comment: @Gimby Feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: @DanielNugent And yet you continue to entertain them by answering their questions. If they aren't willing to modify the question even after multiple comments then they aren't worth bothering with in my opinion. Don't feed the [Help Vampires](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/202529).

Comment: @AdamMatan as you wished. I actually found a feature request that matches exactly what I described.

Comment: what about showing reminder about all self answered questions in last one week. So basically we give reminder once every week (say on Monday) and  only once a week.

Comment: @Lanky true, true. In that case I had flagged the answer as "not an answer" and I was expecting it to be deleted, but I suppose my helpful comments didn't help the overall situation, and my flag was disputed so the answer was never deleted.

Comment: @DanielNugent Whoops well just flagged it again.

Comment: @JonasCz So maybe the solution is just to have someone post a question about this on Meta every couple of weeks? :)

Comment: What's the percentage of self-answered questions that are actually useful compared to ones that are answered with "I forgot a semicolon"?  I would almost say it's better to *not* have a reminder system, so that the Roomba can do its job and clear out junk questions (Roomba won't delete questions with an accepted answer).

Comment: Why don't you do it automatically if there is no answer after two days and the user has attempted to check his or her answer previously?

Comment: @TaylorCourtney Because often I review, edit or refine my answer 2-3 days after my initial solution.

Answer (score 17):

I'd think that the solution would simply be in your user profile. Who needs notifications when you have a simple list that you can periodically check as you can pull this wider than only self-answers - to all questions you asked but did not accept any answer to yet. You actually already get notifications for answers other people provide in the top bar of the site, and even those are not going to serve as any kind of "reminder" to be honest. Just a one-time poke.

But it doesn't seem like your user profile has an "not accepted" filter for your own personal question list. And as per [this existing feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275480/a-list-of-my-questions-without-an-accepted-answer) that asks for exactly what I describe here, there indeed isn't any yet nor do I see any inclination that this feature is planned.

It does however suggest a way to get the list anyway with search filters:

> user:me hasaccepted:no answers:1

Courtesy goes to [nkjt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275488/424903) for that information.

Still, that filter in your user CP seems like a Nice to have. Vote on the linked feature request if you agree.

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is that _you_ still need to periodically check. No automation. From my perspective its basically just as bad.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg yep. You also need to periodically check the notifications you got.

Comment: Thats much easier though. That is displayed to you as a bright red icon every time you go on any page of the site. Checking some random query page (the link for which you need to remember) is out of the way.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg you're talking about the existing notification indicator; even someone as mildly active as me gets too many of them already for that to be quite chaotic, I feel sorry for people who basically live on this site. I'd rather have an easy to find list that can be checked at your leisure - which is when you're not bogged down with real work for example. Keeping in mind that this won't be a list you need to check very often at all, at least I hope!

Comment: I guess thats a point of difference between us. I consider myself active on this site and they don't bother me that much. I would much rather have another notification for this reminders.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg perhaps write up your own answer to make it official :)

Answer (score 2):

> Leaving it as-is generates unaccepted questions for no good reason.

I disagree with this premise (and you do too, in the beginning of your question). It's exceedingly rare that someone will ask a question with supreme confidence that their self-answer is the best and most complete one (Okay, Boltclock, we know you're a CSS guru...). The waiting period itself isn't what's generating an unanswered question; the asker is free to accept an answer from someone else at any time, assuming another person has answered the question.

At the risk of sounding overly academic here, Stack Overflow is a site primarily for good answers to good questions about programming. I often like to say that it's pure coincidence that there is a user attached to a given question or answer; the only reason for reputation is because users are necessary to perform the function of populating the site with content; if robots could do it, they probably would.

As such, this waiting period is designed to let a broader audience see the answer and contribute to the question in an attempt to populate the site with more and better content. Their incentive is usually reputation, 15 of which is possible from getting their answer accepted. I don't have any stats to show you here, but I seem to recall one of the devs (probably Shog) saying somewhere--and I think it's pretty evident to everyone--that questions with accepted answers receive much less attention in the form of new answers, for obvious reasons.

This waiting period is to ensure a reasonable amount of people have a reasonable amount of time to see and answer the question with the possibility of getting accepted and earning them that extra reputation for their work.

It may turn out that [your own answer isn't the best one after all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393931/faking-the-has-parent-selector-using-only-css).

Comment: As far as I understand, nobody is arguing against the waiting period. The problem is that 2 days are sometimes enough to forget about a question you already dealt with, and not having a reminder hurts a little.

Comment: Wouldn't this go for any answer, written by anyone? (OK, not *anyone*, some people here can't be challenged). When a question is answered, there is no guarantee that it's the best one. If it solved the problem though, and it was a good answer, wouldn't it be incorrect to not accept it? I believe the same goes with self answers. If you have a problem, and solved it, and posted a good answer to your own question, accept it. If we didn't accept answers because "someone else might write a better one", then I wouldn't accept my answers unless the top user in that tag answered...

Comment: Not to mention that the OP isn't disagreeing with the waiting period, he's just asking for a reminder system.

Comment: Actually, TylerH is arguing that leaving unaccepted isn't a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a "Read later" feature that also enables you to set a reminder. It would not only cover your specific point, but would also be an overall enhancement that would worth implementing.

Comment: Are "favorite questions" not enough for this? Personally, I use them exactly as "read later" bookmarks.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Why would you favorite a question that you haven't even read? Well, you could use this way, but in my opinion this is mislead. Favorites should be used to tell which question you really like, and not the ones which you want to read later. Mixing favorite with read later questions is actually very confusing.

Comment: I wouldn't star a question I didn't read (and it's pretty much impossible btw, the star only appears when you open the question). If I'm not inclined to read it now, why would I want to come back to it later? On the other hand, some questions are too much for me to digest in one read; I'd star those. Oh yeah, and I upvote questions I like, rather than starring them.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, sometimes I also favorite a question that I want to read later. My point is that users are very creative and often misuse a feature to fulfill some unsupported feature. But this isn't enough: in my opinion we are just working around a bad design.

Comment: Answers to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313130/4350586 suggest that people are not misusing this feature: favorites are **specifically designed** as a way to navigate to questions you want to check upon.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Again, people are creative. Sometimes I want to read later a favorite, sometimes not. Sometimes a question I do is one of my favorite ones, sometimes not. Favorite notifies activity. Read later reminds regardless of activity. If you still disagree, feel free to downvote :D