# Image centering in questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, images

Many posts contain useful images within them - screenshots, UI examples etc.

I would like to argue that the natural alignment of images should be centered. Center alignment is more aesthetically pleasing, and it differentiates the image from the textual flow. This is especially important when the image contains text ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317558/reminder-to-accept-my-own-answer)): centering it would separate the text in the image from the text of the question.

Comment: Simple (but not very effective) workarounds: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/is-it-possible-to-horizontally-center-an-image-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: @Mat Wow! that *is* a broken solution; it bypasses the natural markdown of the site. By the way, any reason why this is downvoted rather than debated?

Comment: I don't really know why there has been so much resistance over the years to add support for this. I suppose part of the problem is that Markdown doesn't have a way to express it, so we would have to add our own custom extension, increasing complexity.

Comment: Yes, not a very good solution, probably doesn't work well on mobiles/tablets as well. (Speculating about why someone would downvote this is probably as useful as a spaces vs tabs debate.)

Comment: I down-voted this because I disagree with the aesthetic point -- it's entirely opinion based and I didn't feel trying to "debate" it would be worthwhile. Nothing personal.