# Time as a search parameter

Tags: feature-request, search

Isn't it possible to use time as a search parameter here on Stack Overflow?

Recently I tried to find out about building a GUI with different Microsoft technologies, but most answers here on Stack Overflow are from 2009. Nobody can really use those to answer *if this technology still in use*, with posts from 6 years ago.

Comment: somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use advanced search parameters to narrow down your search to specific dates or date ranges. See the [*How do I search*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) help page:

> #### Dates
>
> You can use specific dates or date ranges to narrow results down to posts created or active within a certain time period, using the following operators:
>
> - `created`: to specify when the posts were created
> - `lastactive`: for posts active in a specified time period

and goes on to describe how you can specify the dates.

For example, you can limit your search to only include posts created since 2012:

```
created:2012..
```