# How to search all questions I have answered within a tag for a time range?

Tags: support

Is it possible to search all the questions that I have answered for a particular tag within a set time range (e.g. from 01 Jan 2015 to 31 Mar 2015)?

It seems that I can search all my answers for a particular tag, but I can't figure out how to add a date criteria to my search.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162064/248731

Comment: For Java, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1033422+%5Bjava%5D+is%3Aanswer+created%3A2015-01-01..2015-03-31

Comment: I have an open feature request for an advanced search that would make these types of searches simpler: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search

Answer (score 2):

The site search does have an option to restrict the posts by their creationdate with the query option `created`, as indicated by [TLama](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289765/how-to-search-all-questions-i-have-answered-within-a-tag-for-a-time-range#comment174470_289765).

Your search will look like this:

> [`user:1033422 [java] is:answer created:2015-01-01..2015-03-31`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1033422+%5Bjava%5D+is%3Aanswer+created%3A2015-01-01..2015-03-31)

If you want to have a bit more control over what the search for you can also leverage [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), for example with this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/507463?tag=java&startdate=2015-01-01&enddate=2015-03-01&UserId=1033422)

```
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , q.creationdate [Question Created]
     , p.creationdate [AnswerCreated]
     , q.lastactivitydate [Question last active]
     , p.lastactivitydate
 from posts p
 inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
 inner join posttags pt on q.id = pt.postid
 inner join tags t on t.id =pt.tagid
 where p.owneruserid = ##userid:int?1033422##
 and t.tagname = ##tag:string?java##
 and p.creationdate 
     between ##startdate:string?2015-01-01##
     and ##enddate:string?2015-03-01##
```

Note that you can't search for deleted posts in SEDE. On the site search you might search for your own deleted posts with `deleted:1` when you have 10K.