# Way to search within my posts for a word or phrase

Tags: support, search

I know that I can search through my answers via a particular tag.

Even so, since I have lots of posts, sometimes it is still really hard to find the post I'm looking for since the bulk of my posts are within just a few tags.

Usually I do remember certain words or phrases within my answer.

Is there a way to search my posts with a certain search term?

Comment: this might be of use: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`user:me is:answer hello world`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer+hello+world)

You can find all available search operators in the [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) help article.

Comment: Thanks, believe it or not I've actually never stumbled upon that 'how do I search' article!

Comment: @Danield There's an "Advanced Search Tips" link at the top of the search results page sidebar. All the basic operators are there, and also a link to that article.