# How do I search for posts I've interacted on, with a particular word in them?

Tags: support, search, data-explorer

To expand on the question in the title, I want to be able to search for a particular search word or phrase.

I want to limit the result set to posts/pages where I wrote the question, answer, or commented on the page.

However, I may not have used the phrase myself.

e.g. (contrived example) I want to find a post about "SQLiteAssetHelper". I can't remember exactly if I posted an answer or a comment, and I don't know if **I** used that exact word. But it would have been somewhere on that page, probably in someone else's answer.

---

This is related to, but not a duplicate of:

- [Search within my answers/questions/favorites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258415/search-within-my-answers-questions-favorites)
- [Way to search within my posts for a word or phrase](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296553/way-to-search-within-my-posts-for-a-word-or-phrase)

I want to search in everyone's posts, not just mine.

Again using the above example, I could search on `user:me SQLiteAssetHelper`, and it would return a single post that I have answered:

- [Proper way to copy database from /assets to app's private storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579910/proper-way-to-copy-database-from-assets-to-apps-private-storage/23579982#23579982)

But are there others that I have interacted on, where *I did not specifically use that phrase*?

---

Another example would be that I want to find a post about database upgrades that I found interesting a few days back. I remember the solution had something to do with running the comment `adb install -r` with an Android device. I know I commented on it.

A search for `"adb install -r"` comes up with 63 entries.

How do I make a search that just shows this entry:

- [How to test what will happen when you publish an update to your app to the Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993946/how-to-test-what-will-happen-when-you-publish-an-update-to-your-app-to-the-marke)?

Comment: The on-site search of course doesn't look at comments. For comments, you'd have to resort to google search or data explorer queries.

Answer (score 3):

Out of inspiration of your question, I began to toy with composing queries on [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). I created [this ugly query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/351606/453791/search-content-of-posts-im-active-on) that will essentially, gather a list of all questions, answers, and comments from question posts in which you have either:

- Asked the question;
- Posed an answer; or
- Made a comment

Then it will search each post/comment in the list for the indicated text and present the results of any posts or comments from any user, containing the desired phrase.

**Re-disclaimer**: I don't usually do a lot of SQL besides your basic CRUD operations. So the query can definitely be improved. But for the occasional one-off search, it works. The screenshot below indicates a fairly instant response, but that's cached. The initial search response time was 12000ms.

[image: Cached run of the query]