# The ability to search for answers to your own questions

Tags: feature-request, answers, search

Stack Overflow's search feature allows me to search for my own questions and answers using `user:me`, but it doesn't allow me to search for answers to my questions posted by other users.

I want to find an answer that I know was posted to one of my questions, but I have no idea which one.

Can we please have a function to search for answers to our questions?

---

As a temporary workaround, the [Advanced Search for answers posted to your questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/131059/advanced-search-for-answers-posted-to-your-questions) Data Explorer query given in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193707/192654) works rather well.

Comment: By default you search in both questions and answers. If you want just one post type, you add `is:q` or `is:a` to your query.

Comment: Really? That's odd, I could've sworn it wasn't searching the answers. Thank you @approxiblue, I didn't know those modifiers existed!

Comment: Mmm I'm not sure if what you said is true @approxiblue. For example, this question of mine contains [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29556339/1391441) that mentions the word "AxisArtist". If I [search for that word](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1391441+AxisArtist) I get no results back.

Comment: No, it absolutely does search answers.  See all the A: it brings up here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1228+datatemplate you seem to have found a corner case or a bug. I'd **strongly** suggest you edit to turn this into a bug report with the info from your comment.

Comment: It does search *answers posted by me*, but it doesn't search *answers to my questions*. There's no way to do that with the built-in search function

Comment: Now I'm confused. According to @TinyGiant it does *not* search answers to my questions.

Comment: There was a misunderstanding, the other users were thinking you were asking about searching *your own answers*, not *answers to your questions*

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll change the tag back to support then. Thanks @TinyGiant.

Comment: Yeah, what @TinyGiant said. I thought you meant your answers, but you meant answers to your questions.

Comment: Well the answer to your question is "No.", maybe you want to change it to [tag:feature-request] and clarify that you're specifically looking for answers to questions that you've posted.

Comment: Done @TinyGiant, thanks again!

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [How to search answers to my questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193706/21960)

Comment: @ale That is *so much more* efficient than [the way I did it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302770/3773066).  I included comments, but still, it's slow and I had very little clue what I was doing when I made it. =]