# Better questions list options at SO index

Tags: feature-request

By now, questions at the home screen in SO are listed in order of time and there is the favorite tag filter. Despite the "categories" (interesting, featured, hot, week and month) I found it really hard to find questions that I can/want to answer. Is is that hard to implement some quick filters like:

- order list by answers/views/votes
- show only question with no answers/views of a specific tag (or group of tags)
- option to costumize the "smart sort" the list based on your user data (this would be awesome)

So, is there a reason not to have something like that? What's your guys opinions about it? I hope this suggestion will make our website and community more productive!!!

Comment: take a look at an old question of mine regarding the advanced search features: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search you can run this sample to use it if you like: http://jsfiddle.net/4qzfa9ft/8/embedded/result/

Comment: *"option to "smart sort" the list based on your user data"* The homepage currently does this. I use it about 50% of the time to find questions to answer. The other 50%, I search by hand-chosen combinations of tags and look at the newest questions.

Comment: an example search query it could generate: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+answers%3A0+score%3A1+created%3A2017-01+intags%3Amine, would be questions from this month with a positive score and 0 answers in your tags.

Comment: Thx a lot. They really should implement that advanced search @Tanner, but what I'm asking is the ability to have a "custom search" in the home screen. Oh and that custom search is great, it's on my favorite bar! We could have some control over that smart sort feature, don't you think @cody-gray?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto That's already the case.  The homepage *doesn't* just sort by newest, it *does* have options to show unanswered questions, and you can configure it through, for example, changing your tags.

Comment: Were can I find this option @Servy?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Click the "unanswered" button.

Comment: That isn't an option @Servy, thats a link my friend

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto yes, it's a link, and you can click it to see unanswered questions.

Comment: cookies could remember the most searched tags to assume a personal interest to filter on

Comment: Also every click to a Q is related to tags that could update a freq table in cookie

Answer (score -8, accepted):

So after @Servy comment I found an option that gives something really close to what I asked.

To access it go to:

- Your Profile >
- Edit Profile & Settings >
- Preferences (under Site settings) >
- New Navigation (Beta Feature) >
- I would like to participate in testing the new navigation (check this box)

It gives the user the ability to create custom tags at the home screen with custom tag searches.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Keep up @rafaelcastrocouto. I think tags can serve us better. Some automation that can be adjusted in preferences.

Comment: So you don't like the site, it's rules, it's moderators, or basically any part of it, and you want the entire site to change to how you want it to be, even though it works as it is for solo many people _because_ it works the way it works. That makes no sense. I suggest finding a site that does work that way and joining up there.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'd actually pay to sign up to a site that works like that, just to witness the complete madness of a site which radically changes every 5 seconds.

Answer (score -5):

What if ...

cookies could remember the most searched tags to assume a personal interest to filter on

Also every click to a Q is related to tags that could update a freq table in cookie

Comment: They already do this, you can see the data for your account at https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data

Comment: Wonderful! They got me by Javascript Html Css. Wonder what info is hided in the decimals ;)