# Can I filter my answers on whether they are accepted or not accepted?

Tags: support, profile-page, accepted-answer

In my user profile, I can see my list of answers and I can filter by votes, activity or newest.

Is it possible to filter this list to see only the accepted answers or the not-accepted?

Comment: search for `user:me is:answer isaccepted:yes`

Comment: very loosely related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search

Answer (score 6):

Use search; go to the top-right search box on your profile, where your userid is already prefilled, or use `user:me`, then add search terms.

To filter on answers, use `is:a`. To filter on accepted answers, use `isaccepted:yes`, while un-accepted answers are found with `isaccepted:no` (the `isaccepted:` filter automatically restricts the search to answers only).