# Search box allows empty and whitespace input

Tags: feature-request, search

When I click on search button without entering the data it is navigating to blank page.

Also, whitespaces is not trimmed, but quoted instead:

[image]

The search should sanitize the input fields.

Comment: What sanitization would you like to see happen exactly, and why? Also, if you want to explicitly search for seven spaces, why should the search engine deny that?

Comment: The input Field in an application should have self validation. For empty input also it is sending request and getting response from server.if it has self validation it will not send response to server.it will improve the performance of the application

Answer (score 11):

I'd say this is fine as is.

If you don't enter a search term and hit the search button, you'll be shown a search page without any results, where you can build an advanced search query with help visible:

[image: Advanced Search Tips]

So the search page is one click away, and you aren't required to enter a bogus search term to get there.

> [it will improve the performance of the application](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343856/search-box-allows-empty-and-whitespace-input?noredirect=1#comment448316_343856)

Besides the fact that the only people who can say something sensible about Stack Overflow's performance are the people implementing its software and monitoring its servers, the current behavior is actually already the best performance you can get, because when there's nothing to search, nothing will be searched.

Then the not trimming whitespace does look like a bug, because it finds nothing for even a single space, which I'm sure quite a few posts contain.

Comment: if only that page looked something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcrOo.png), from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search